reproduce an analysis of a simple crossover trial using GEE from a paper
I am trying to reproduce the results in Table 6 from this paper entitled "The analysis of binary and categorical data from crossover trials". https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/epdf/10.1177/096228029400300403. The aggregated data is given in Table 1.
Here is my attempt to fit a logistic regression from individual data in R:
########### create individual data from aggregated data given in Table 1:
countdat <- rbind(c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,0,2,4),
                  c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,3,9),
                  c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,5),
                  c(1,0,1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,4,0,10))
indiv_dat <- NULL
outcomes <- cbind(rep(0:1,each=8),rep(rep(0:1,each=4),2),rep(rep(0:1,each=2),4),rep(0:1,8))
for (i in 1:4) {
  rows <- 1:nrow(outcomes)
  index <- rep(rows,countdat[i,] )
  indiv_dat <- rbind(indiv_dat,outcomes[index,])  
}
#head(indiv_dat,18)

indiv_dat <- as.data.frame(indiv_dat)
names(indiv_dat) <- paste("Period",1:4)

indiv_dat$ID <- 1:80
indiv_dat$seq <- rep(1:4, c(18,22,19,21))

longdat <- reshape(indiv_dat,direction= "long",idvar = "ID",varying = paste("Period",1:4),v.names="success",timevar = "period")

treatment <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(longdat)){
  obs <- longdat[i,c("seq","period")]
  if(sum(obs==c(1,1)) == 2| sum(obs==c(2,3)) == 2 |sum(obs==c(3,2)) == 2|sum(obs==c(4,4)) == 2) treatment[i] <- "A"
  if(sum(obs==c(1,2)) == 2| sum(obs==c(2,1)) == 2 |sum(obs==c(3,4)) == 2|sum(obs==c(4,3)) == 2) treatment[i] <- "B"
  if(sum(obs==c(1,3)) == 2| sum(obs==c(2,4)) == 2 |sum(obs==c(3,1)) == 2|sum(obs==c(4,2)) == 2) treatment[i] <- "C"
  if(sum(obs==c(1,4)) == 2| sum(obs==c(2,2)) == 2 |sum(obs==c(3,3)) == 2|sum(obs==c(4,1)) == 2) treatment[i] <- "D"
}
longdat$treatment <- treatment

> ################ results in  Table 6
> logismodel <-  glm(success~ period+treatment, data=longdat, family=binomial())
> summary(logismodel)

Call:
glm(formula = success ~ period + treatment, family = binomial(), 
    data = longdat)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.750  -1.391   0.801   0.881   1.064  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.4436     0.3876    3.72   0.0002 ***
period       -0.1567     0.1096   -1.43   0.1527    
treatmentB   -0.5430     0.3449   -1.57   0.1154    
treatmentC   -0.0696     0.3578   -0.19   0.8458    
treatmentD   -0.3275     0.3502   -0.94   0.3497    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 395.9  on 319  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 390.9  on 315  degrees of freedom
AIC: 400.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> 
> #### coeftest function from lmtest package to calcuate sandwich estimator
> coeftest(logismodel, vcov = sandwich)

z test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.4436     0.4097    3.52  0.00043 ***
period       -0.1567     0.1122   -1.40  0.16243    
treatmentB   -0.5430     0.3478   -1.56  0.11844    
treatmentC   -0.0696     0.3604   -0.19  0.84694    
treatmentD   -0.3275     0.3523   -0.93  0.35244    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

From the output above, the sandwich estimator generated by coeftest(logismodel, vcov = sandwich) are 0.3478, 0.3604, 0.3523, which are not the same as Table 6 in the paper (0.33, 0.32,0.28, respectively).
I have also tried geeglm function in the geepack package:
> geemod <- geeglm(formula(success~ period+treatment), family = "binomial", data = longdat, 
+                  id = ID,corstr = "independence")
> 
> summary(geemod)

Call:
geeglm(formula = formula(success ~ period + treatment), family = "binomial", 
    data = longdat, id = ID, corstr = "independence")

 Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)   1.4436  0.4097 12.41  0.00043 ***
period       -0.1567  0.1122  1.95  0.16243    
treatmentB   -0.5430  0.3478  2.44  0.11844    
treatmentC   -0.0696  0.3604  0.04  0.84694    
treatmentD   -0.3275  0.3523  0.86  0.35244    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = independence 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)        1  0.0707
Number of clusters:   320  Maximum cluster size: 1 
> 
> geemod <- geeglm(formula(success~ period+treatment), family = "binomial", data = longdat, 
+        id = ID,corstr = "exchangeable")
> 
> summary(geemod)

Call:
geeglm(formula = formula(success ~ period + treatment), family = "binomial", 
    data = longdat, id = ID, corstr = "exchangeable")

 Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)   1.4436  0.4097 12.41  0.00043 ***
period       -0.1567  0.1122  1.95  0.16243    
treatmentB   -0.5430  0.3478  2.44  0.11844    
treatmentC   -0.0696  0.3604  0.04  0.84694    
treatmentD   -0.3275  0.3523  0.86  0.35244    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = exchangeable 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)        1  0.0707
  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha        0       0
Number of clusters:   320  Maximum cluster size: 1 
> 
> geemod <- geeglm(formula(success~ period+treatment), family = "binomial", data = longdat, 
+                  id = ID,corstr = "ar1")
> 
> summary(geemod)

Call:
geeglm(formula = formula(success ~ period + treatment), family = "binomial", 
    data = longdat, id = ID, corstr = "ar1")

 Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)   1.4436  0.4097 12.41  0.00043 ***
period       -0.1567  0.1122  1.95  0.16243    
treatmentB   -0.5430  0.3478  2.44  0.11844    
treatmentC   -0.0696  0.3604  0.04  0.84694    
treatmentD   -0.3275  0.3523  0.86  0.35244    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = ar1 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)        1  0.0707
  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha        0       0
Number of clusters:   320  Maximum cluster size: 1 

Questions:

How is the sandwich estimator generated in Table 6 from the paper?
Using geeglm function from geepack, why the sandwich estimators are the same using three different correlation structures, i.e., independence, exchangeable, ar1 ?


There are three issues with the attempt to reproduce the marginal analysis.
Most obviously, R interprets period as a numerical variable, not as categorical variable with four levels, one for each period. That's why the summary tables report one coefficient for the period, rather than three coefficients — period2, period3, period4 with period1 as the reference level.
The next issue is more subtle and only affects geepack::geeglm which expects that the data is sorted by cluster (ie. by subject ID). Here is the relevant section of the documentation:

id: a vector which identifies the clusters. The length of ‘id’ should be the same as the number of observations. Data are assumed to be sorted so that observations on each cluster appear as contiguous rows in data. If data is not sorted this way, the function will not identify the clusters correctly. If data is not sorted this way, a warning will be issued. Please consult the package vignette for details.

And finally the sequence of steps:
logismodel <- glm(success ~ period + treatment, family = binomial())
coeftest(logismodel, vcov = sandwich)

don't specify that the cluster variable is ID, so the clustered standard errors are not calculated correctly. One way to specify the covariance structure is to use sandwich::vcovCL.
Next I fit the marginal model two ways: (a) using glm and clustered standard errors computed with vcovCL, and (b) using geeglm. I use dplyr to apply the necessary data transformations.
fit1 <- glm(
    success ~ period + treatment,
    data = longdat,
    family = binomial()
)

# cadjust = FALSE: Don't apply cluster adjustment.
cov.mat <- vcovCL(fit1, type = "HC0", cluster = ~ID, cadjust = FALSE)
coeftest(fit1, vcov = cov.mat)
#> z test of coefficients:
#> 
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
#> (Intercept)  1.112777   0.345825  3.2177 0.001292 **
#> period2      0.371626   0.316982  1.1724 0.241041   
#> period3     -0.246656   0.297168 -0.8300 0.406527   
#> period4     -0.315721   0.285422 -1.1062 0.268658   
#> treatmentB  -0.536652   0.325212 -1.6502 0.098910 . 
#> treatmentC  -0.081347   0.322781 -0.2520 0.801026   
#> treatmentD  -0.341037   0.275493 -1.2379 0.215748

Next the explicit GEE analysis with geeglm. The first step is two sort the data by subject ID as required.
longdat <- longdat |>
  arrange(
    ID, period
  )

fit2 <- geeglm(
  success ~ period + treatment,
  id = ID,
  data = longdat,
  family = binomial()
)
summary(fit2)
#>  Coefficients:
#>             Estimate  Std.err   Wald Pr(>|W|)   
#> (Intercept)  1.11278  0.34583 10.354  0.00129 **
#> period2      0.37163  0.31698  1.374  0.24104   
#> period3     -0.24666  0.29717  0.689  0.40653   
#> period4     -0.31572  0.28542  1.224  0.26866   
#> treatmentB  -0.53665  0.32521  2.723  0.09891 . 
#> treatmentC  -0.08135  0.32278  0.064  0.80103   
#> treatmentD  -0.34104  0.27549  1.532  0.21575   

